# Internal Server Error (500) - When deploy Flask App on IIS (Only Pages with API Pulling Data)

Tags: xml, api, flask, iis, soap

I try hosting my flask app on localhost. All pages works fine.
When I deploy on IIS Server, some pages shows internal server error (500).
When I check the pages that has internal server error because, those specific routes, is sending request to an API to pull data. If I remove the API it works perfectly fine. But I need the API to be there, API is pulling data from database.

SOAP API - ASMX WebService

Below is how i use the api and get the content/data.
`response = requests.get('api') soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml') data = []`

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: IIS is very restrictive and you do not have access to machines resources like the file system.  If you are using files put then on a network drive (not c:\) where you have access.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.